# Google Play Console - Fill tax information

Tags: taxes, form-w-8-ben

I appreciate any help anyone can give me with this. I believe many other people are facing the same problem so this question could act as a reference point for them.

I am trying to fill my tax information on Google play console but they their form uses some very hard to understand language for someone that doesn't have a background in this sort of thing.

My scenario is that I have a company in Romania and I am a resident of Greece. I have only published one app in Play store (as my company) that sells subscriptions to users so that they can use the app. It also shows ads using AdMob. I selected the W-8BEN-E form (I hope that was the correct option for my case. Please confirm if you know.)

**First question**

In the following part my understanding is that I should select No and check the checkbox below but before I do that I wanted to ask the community about it to confirm that this is what I should do. Google support is completely useless. They just tell me to hire a tax expert in the US which 1) I don't even know how to do and 2) It would cost me at least 500$ just for a couple of simple questions which I can't invest at this time.

[image]

**Second question** is about the Tax treaty.

1. Is this relevant to my case since I only have revenue through subscriptions and AdMob?
2. It asks "Resident of country claiming treaty with the US". The "Resident" part refers to my company not me personally right?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

So, I am already 8 months late to answer this. But I had created a new account to help you, hope it helps anyone who is looking for a similar kind of thing.

Yes if you are registering as a Registered Business on the Play console, then you have to submit that W-8BEN-E form.
(Note: W-8BEN is for an Individual)

**First Question**, yes you should check NO, in the first question you have asked.

(**Explanation for why you should check NO:** Because you are not operating in the USA. If you have an office, or your company has any operations going on in USA, then you should tick yes. But as you mentioned in the question, your company is based and working in Romania and operating from there, then NO is the appropriate answer).

**Second Question**, Definitely yes, the Tax treaty is relevant. Income from ads or IAP or subscriptions is tax-deductible at 30% withholding of your income by the USA tax authority. If you don't use the Tax treaty, you will be Double Taxed in the USA and then in your resident country.

Yes, the Resident is your company. When you register your business officially as Company/LLP/Partnership, now you both are two different legal entities. So, as you are submitting W-8BEN-E, you have to submit the country of your Company's residence (Not you), that is Romania in your case.
Do read the legal requirement of a Company being a Resident of a Country, every Country have its own laws, so just make it sure. As I am from India, your law might differ.

Disclaimer: I had tried to explain whatever I knew, I am not a Legal or Tax consultant. I am also a developer publishing games on Playstore. Learned through my experience and readings.

You can ask if you have any doubt.

Thank you,

Trishader Games

Comment: Please remove the spam link.

Comment: Welcome, and thank you for taking the time to answer this question! On this site we don’t put promotional links in our posts, but you can add a link to your website on your user profile.

Comment: @Flux It was not a spam link. It was simply a signature link from a new user who didn’t know yet that we don’t do signature links here.

Comment: @BenMiller-RememberMonica Sorry, I was not familiar with the concept of "signature links" as I have never written one before.

Comment: Okay, I didn't know that signature links are not allowed.

Comment: I had removed the link, thanks for informing me @Flux and Ben Miller. Please do not remove this answer as it might be helpful for many people. Thanks again.

Comment: @TrishaderGames It's not a big deal. You are a new user, and you've written a helpful answer to the OP's question. Thank you! Just so you know, it is not only signature links that are against etiquette here at StackExchange, but a signature of any kind at the end of your post is seen as unnecessary, as your username already appears automatically at the end of each of your posts. We are different than most forums in this regard, as we focus solely on questions and answers. Feel free to look at [the tour](https://money.stackexchange.com/tour) to learn more about how StackExchange sites work.

Comment: @TrishaderGames Your answer was very helpful. However I am stuck in the next step. When I choose "yes" in the treaty question, there is this checkbox that says - "Derives the item(s) of income for which the treaty benefits are claimed, and, if applicable, meets the requirements of the treaty provision dealing with limitation on benefits" -> What do I choose here? any ideas?

Comment: @UdayadityaBarua Can you please provide more details or a screenshot? Maybe you can ask a question with a screenshot where you are stuck and tag me there. I will respond as soon as I check that.